# Show bookmark icon on safari on password protected website

Tags: .htaccess, mobile-safari, favicon, bookmarks

When adding a password protected website to bookmarks or favorites the icon does not appear on safari. However the icon is appearing next to the titel and when adding the website to the homescreen. After removing the password protection the icon appeared in the bookmarks. Is there a way to let the icon appear when the website is password protected?
I currently use a .htaccess file for the password protection and Apache 2.4.43.

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "(img/favicon.png)$" allow
Order allow,deny
Allow from env=allow
Satisfy any
```

Comment: How have you currently implemented the password protection? What version of Apache are you on? (The directives you posted above are older Apache 2.2 directives.)

Comment: I currently use a .htaccess file for the password protection and Apache 2.4.43.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following after your password protection directives:

```
<Files "favicon.png">
    Require all granted
</Files>
```

Comment: The bookmark or favorite icon is still not appearing. However Safari can access the files when adding the website to the homescreen.

Comment: Can you access `favicon.png` directly in the browser without being prompted for login?

Comment: Yes, I can access the file directly.

Comment: So what else is Safari trying to access that is preventing the icon from showing? (Since you stated that "After removing the password protection the icon appeared in the bookmarks") Check your server's access log for any requests that Safari is making and the corresponding HTTP response status.

Comment: I checked the response status - Safari is getting the exact same results, but is however demanding more files without password protection - but the "extra demanded" files all have the response code 404.

Comment: With the password protection enabled then you should be seeing a 401 response for these "extra demanded" files? Maybe Safari prefers a 404?

Comment: Yes, you're right it's "401 381" - other files had 404, but for other reasons...